# Bash command-line to rename wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

In my `/opt/myapp` dir I have a remote, automated process that will be dropping files of the form `<anything>-<version>.zip`, where `<anything>` could literally be *any* alphanumeric filename, and where `<version>` will be a version number. So, examples of what this automated process will be delivering are:

- `fizz-0.1.0.zip`
- `buzz-1.12.35.zip`
- `foo-1.0.0.zip`
- `bar-3.0.9.RC.zip`

etc. Through controls outside the scope of this question, I am **guaranteed** that only one of these ZIP files will exist under `/opt/myapp` at any given time. I need to write a *Bash shell command* that will rename these files and move them to `/opt/staging`. For the rename, the ZIP files need to have their version dropped. And so `/opt/myapp/<anything>-<version>.zip` is renamed and moved to `/opt/staging/<anything>.zip`. Using the examples above:

- `/opt/myapp/fizz-0.1.0.zip` => `/opt/staging/fizz.zip`
- `/opt/myapp/buzz-1.12.35.zip` => `/opt/staging/buzz.zip`
- `/opt/myapp/foo-1.0.0.zip` => `/opt/staging/foo.zip`
- `/opt/myapp/bar-3.0.9.RC.zip` => `/opt/staging/bar.zip`

The directory move is obvious and easy, but the rename is making me pull my hair out. I need to somehow save off the `<anything>` and then re-access it later on in the command. **The command must be generic and can take no arguments.**

My best attempt (which doesn't even come close to working) so far is:

> file=*.zip; file=?; mv file /opt/staging

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Thanks @chepner but **please unmark as dupe!** In that question the user *knew* that the word "doc" would always appear in the filename, here I'm not sure what `<anything>` is!!! **This is not the same question and requires a different solution!** Flagging for moderation.

Comment: How does that make it different? (That the suggested duplicate is no longer linked makes it hard to tell whether/why its solutions would or would not work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in *.zip; do
  [[ -e $file ]] || continue # handle zero-match case without nullglob
  mv -- "$file" /opt/staging/"${file%-*}.zip"
done
```

`${file%-*}` removes everything after the last `-` in the filename. Thus, we change `fizz-0.1.0.zip` to `fizz`, and then add a leading `/opt/staging/` and a trailing `.zip`.

---

To make this more generic (working with multiple extensions), see the following function (callable as a command; function body could also be put into a script with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, if one removed the `local` declarations):

```
stage() {
  local file ext
  for file; do
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue
    [[ $file = *-*.* ]] || {
      printf 'ERROR: Filename %q does not contain a dash and a dot\n' "$file" >&2
      continue
    }
    ext=${file##*.}
    mv -- "$file" /opt/staging/"${file%-*}.$ext"
  done
}
```

...with that function defined, you can run:

```
stage *.zip *.txt
```

...or any other pattern you so choose.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...part of the reason for going the test route being that I gather that the OP wants to call this as a script (which is also why I put in the notes about converting it from a function); can't necessarily control the calling environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=foo-1.3.4.txt
echo ${f%%-*}.${f##*.}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using some fairly obscure shell syntax there, which warrants explanation of what it does.

Comment: @SamB, parameter expansion isn't all that obscure -- and actually, my answer uses it too. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe