# Bash rm command not working from inside loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, glob, substitution, rm

At any given time my Linux server will have the following directory structure under `/opt`:

```
/opt/
    myapp/
        <fileName>-<version>.zip
    <fileName>/
        derp.txt
    staging/
```

Where `<fileName>-<version>.zip` is a ZIP file with a "wildcard" name. One moment it might be `fizz-1.0.1.zip`, in which case the file system would look like:

```
/opt/
    myapp/
        fizz-1.0.1.zip
    fizz/
        derp.txt
    staging/
```

Then an hour later, the file system might look like:

```
/opt/
    myapp/
        buzz-2.11.15.zip
    buzz/
        derp.txt
    staging/
```

I am trying to write a cleanup bash command that will scan the `/opt/myapp` directory for ZIP files (`*.zip`), rename them and move them to `/opt/staging`, as well as to delete the `derp.txt` file. For the rename, I just want to drop the hyphen and version number, so for instance transforming `fizz-1.0.1.zip` into `fizz.zip`. So for instance, running the script when the file system looks like:

```
/opt/
    myapp/
        fizz-1.0.1.zip
    fizz/
        derp.txt
    staging/
```

Should result with:

```
/opt/
    myapp/
    fizz/
    staging/
        fizz.zip
```

I am guaranteed to only have 1 ZIP file inside `/opt/myapp` at any given time. My best attempt is:

```
for file in *.zip; do 
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue
    sudo mv "$file" /opt/staging/"${file%%-*}.zip"
    sudo rm -rf /opt/${file%%-}/derp.txt
done
```

This performs the rename and moving of the ZIP file, but doesn't delete the `derp.txt`. Any ideas as to where I'm going awry?

Comment: Why don't you quote your variables consequently?

Comment: `set -x` is your friend. Put that in your script and you'll see the actual commands it's running, so you can figure out how/why the name munging isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: @hek2mgl It's an adaption of [this well quoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30464685/1899640) with some additions that are not quoted.

Comment: @thatotherguy Probably a stupid question but shouldn't it be `[[ -e "$file" ]]`?

Comment: @hek2mgl Things in `[[ .. ]]` are special, so no, the quotes there are harmless but not necessary.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks, good to know! You see, I'm still unsafe when need to decide if word splitting will happen or not. Give me more time! :)

Comment: BTW, using `rm -rf` on a *file* is a code smell. Drop both options. You expect the file to be there, so `rm file` is all you need and it would have shown you the error immediately. With `-rf` you tell `rm` *I know what I'm doing, shut up*, which you didn't :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't a `*` missing somewhere in `${file%%-}`? As is, it only removes a trailing `-`, if any.